# PHP and MYSQL date format

Tags: php, mysql

```
$Ndate = new DateTime($theValue);

$theValue = "'" . $Ndate->format('Y-m-d') . "'";
```

I have a text box with the name `dateOfjourney` and I want to enter the date in date-month-year format, and store the date in mysql in year-month-day format.

`$theValue` is an sql string which I will use in an SQL statement

Comment: What do you want to store in database? `$Ndate` or `$theValue`?

Comment: i want to want to take the date in m-d-y format from text box and b4 using sql queries convert it into default y-m-d format

Comment: Why would you want to mix standards in your application? Why not work with and save time stamps and then display them in the specified format when shown to the user?

Comment: but here user is entering date and he wants to enter in d-m-y format

Answer (score 4):

The most reliable and hassle free way to insert dates into MYSQL is to use MySql's STR_TO_DATE:

```
STR_TO_DATE('dateOfjourney', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

That way the users can enter whatever they want and on the backend you  have what you want.

Comment: +1 that is pretty good!

Comment: +1, but the format should be `%m-%d-%Y`

Comment: Updated it to reflect the d-m-y format he said his users provide.

Comment: @UselessIntern In the comment he's written about m-d-Y, never mind, really nice solution.

Comment: but str_to_date gives error

Comment: @johnsmith `STR_TO_DATE` should be inserted in the query, not in PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert it using php [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
date("m-d-y",strtotime($theValue));
```

read about [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: I'm always wondering if `strtotime()` can properly say what day it is "01-02-03".

Comment: I am just changing the format of date using strtotime()

Comment: In the USA 01 is month, 02 is day, and 03 is year. So it would be 2nd Jan, 2003. But it can also be 1st Feb of 2003 or 3rd Feb of 2001. I don't like this function because you never know how the server would handle a date.

Comment: we have to set timezone accordingly.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Time zone has nothing with date format. If you get as date user input like "01-02-03" you never know what `strtotime` will do. Take a look [at this](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p7i-126)

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your d-m-Y date in POST data, you can do:

```
$db_date = implode( "-" ,  array_reverse(explode("-" , $date_from_form)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this

```
$user_input = '01-23-2013'; // 23rd of January
list($month, $day, $year) = explode('-',$user_input);
$output = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.3+ you can do:

```
$dateFormatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-y', $dateFromForm)->format('y-m-d');
```